# Vue Router adds # (hash) after calling router.push() in "history" mode

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

On a specific UI action I'm calling:

```js
router.push({ name: router.history.current.name, params: { league: league } })
```

I just want to add "/:league" param at the end of the route. I have a separate route for it:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Home, name: 'home' },
    { path: '/:league', component: Home, props: true, name: 'home/league' },
  ]
})
```

For example if the user is at / and he selects a "league" from a menu, I want the url to change to /leagueName.

It works, but it appends # at the end of the url and it ends up being /leagueName#. Is there a way to remove the hash? I'm already in "history" mode.

Comment: language is not a parameter. Paramaters come after ? in the route sting like ?name=somthing. So need to go another router view, and it's not a good idea to use the same component for it. Check for nested routes https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a separate route that points to the same component, use an optional parameter on one route:

```js
export default new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/:league?", // `?` makes `league` OPTIONAL
      component: Home,
      props: true,
      name: "home"
    }
  ]
});
```

And if you need to use `$router.push()` to change only the parameter value, you could omit the `name` or `path`:

```html
<button @click="$router.push({ params: { league: 'myLeague' } })">
  Go to My League
</button>
```

Note if the UI is intended to be a link, it might be best to use `router-link`, which avoids the `Avoided redundant navigation to current location` console warning:

```html
<router-link :to="{ params: { league: 'myLeague' } }">Go to My League</router-link>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/optional-route-param-in-vue-router-j2ses?file=/src/App.vue)

Answer (score 2):

I found several bugs:

1. Check how your router is [connected](https://router.vuejs.org/installation.html) and configured:

```js
const routes = [
  { path: '/', name: 'Home', component: Home },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

2. You need to write `$router`, when you call a push.
3. You can't write a name like `router.history.current.name`, because you will go to the same page. So state explicitly: `home/league`.
4. Better not use one component to output different routes, this is not very good. But you can use [child routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html).

Comment: Regarding 3. - If I add a param to / doesn't it become /:paramname which is a different route?